# Mongoose unable to find index for $geoNear query

Tags: mongoose, geolocation

I got this error when trying to query a model based on location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After combining some answers on SO, here's the full implementaion.

**Model**

```
// model.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ModelSchema = new Schema({
  location: {
    type: [Number],
    index: '2dsphere'
  }
});

ModelSchema.index({ location: 1});

module.exports = mongoose.model('model', ModelSchema);
```

**Controller**

```
// controller.js
Model = require('path/to/model')
exports.getByLocation = function(req, res, next) {
  var coords = [+req.query.lon, +req.query.lat];

  Model.where('location').near({
      center: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: coords
      }
    })
    .then(function(docs) {
      res.json(docs);
    })
    .catch(next);
}
```

Hope this helps :)